# changing twilio flex login view logo

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-flex

I am trying to change the login view page logo of flex.twilio.com
on a self hosted instance
grabbed from [here](https://github.com/twilio/flex-ui-sample).
As guided by twilio how to change login view logo [here](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/developer/ui/configuration#flex-agent-and-supervisor-ui) ,
I followed this :

```
flex.LoginView.defaultProps.logoUrl = "https://sample-logo-url.svg";
```

But,it doesn't seems to work.
this was a issue raised on another repo [here](https://github.com/twilio/flex-plugin-builder/issues/6),

does anyone have faced similar bug or solved it?

[image]

Comment: I am looking into this, as I was also unable to change that. Will report back soon.